# How to prevent draft.js from removing blocks on Backspace

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I'm currently developing a RichText Editor with Draft.JS and React.JS and
I want to prevent Draft.JS from deleting inserted atomic blocks on backspace, but rather move the cursor into the `textarea` element of the atomic block.

Is this possible and if it is, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is posibble. Just handle the backspace key with your code, do whatever changes to editor's content.

https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-key-bindings/